# Can I use this battery for my circuit?

Tags: power, batteries, pcb, pcb-design, lipo

I plan on having a circuit that connects a 3.7v Lipo battery to a 1.4 ohm coil.
However, I just saw this table for the battery I am using and noticed it has a max discharge of 0.4A

Does this mean I can't use it for my case? I noticed my battery has circuitry combined with the battery so maybe that's what keeps the battery from discharging over 0.4A?

I was hoping to expend ~3A on the 1.4 ohm coil.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, but it will not last long, because the internal resistance is to high.

There are different ways to create a lithium-battery, some use one big sheet and make a roll, but then the resistance is high.
Other factories use several sheets and make a stack of them, this is a bit more complicated, but the resistance is much lower.

If you want to use a e-vape-stick, then you should use a battery which is a bit more powerful.
Normally there are 850mAh LiIon-cells in the ordinary e-vapes and they use 1.8 Ohm coils.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's what confuses me. Juul has a 200 mAh battery and Vuse Alto has 350 mAh battery, both are LiPo batteries. Maybe they aren't sending 2-3 A over their coil?

Comment: @MichaelRutkowski - There are different types, they are different made. They use the same components, but put it a little bit different together. If the internal resistance is to high, then the cell gets possibly to hot and the electrolyte can change chemical because of the internal heat and then the cell creates gas and blows up. There are tiny 160mAh cells which can supply 1.6A without get damaged, because the layers are stacked together!

Comment: Okay, so not all LiPo batteries are created the same, there are more differences than their mAh and nominal voltage?

Comment: @MichaelRutkowski - Yes. The better cells are a bit more expensive, because there are more work-steps to create them. There are cells made for drones, they can deliver 10 times more current as their capacity-value. 400mAh -> 4A